# Keydown script only working when placing the script code below the input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

When I place the script code above the text box it is not working but if I place code below the input field then it works.

```
<script src="js/jQueryv3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    alert();
});
</script>

<input type="number" id="phoneNo" />
```

DOES NOT WORK

BUT BELOW WORKS

```
<script src="js/jQueryv3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="number" id="phoneNo" />

<script>
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    alert();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. But anyway, in the first one the browser executes the script *before* the input element has been parsed, so `$("input")` can't find it. If you want to put the script above, you have to use a document ready handler to delay execution of any code that tries to access DOM elements.

Comment: @phpNoob this is where you need to see the **.load(), .ready()** events of jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code with $(document).ready() like:

```
$(function() {
    $("input").keydown(function(e){
        alert();
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").keydown(function(e){
        alert();
    });
});
```

jQuery unable to find the input element when you define it before the input box, But when you write the same after the input box that time it will get the information about the input box.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to attach a handler to an alreadt defined element, you can use

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    alert();
});
```

as you have already used.

However, if you want to attach a event handler to a dynamic element ( one you are creating later on ), you can use :

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e){
    alert();
});
```

Comment: The OP's code doesn't include any dynamically created elements.